# wp e-commerce single-product template giving 404

Tags: templates, 404-error, plugin-wp-e-commerce

this page was working initially, and then I made some changes which ****didn’t**** appear, and then it just stopped showing that page altogether.

I have tried deleting my `wpsc-single_product.php` and replacing it with the default one provided but it still just shows 404.

My category page does the same, in fact the only pages I can get to work are the ones that are actual pages (checkout, transaction results etc.) - this made me think it could be a url rewrite problem but considering it was working before and I haven’t made any changes to my .htaccess or infact any other file it probably isn’t.

Shouldn't it default to the `wpsc-single_product.php` file that is in the plugin directory anyway - like it did before I copied the file over in the first place?

What could have made this happen?! Please help?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice,
Billy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in the end.

There is a button in the wpsc settings page under presentation to flush the theme cache.

Caption:

> If you have moved your files in some other way i.e FTP, you may need to click the Flush Theme Cache. This will refresh the locations WordPress looks for your templates.

Simple, and hard to miss, but I managed to!